# Adding samples from wav files without causing integer overflow

Tags: design, c

Recently, I've been writing a wav writer in C. For this question of mine, Let's consider two wav files that we'll be combining the samples; both are s16le mono wav files to be simple.

The first idea that struck in my mind for combining the samples of this wav files was just adding them together.

To illustrate it, here's an example of the 1st sample from some two wav files:

```
       Wav file 1  Wav file 2
       1st sample  1st sample
Hex:     20 03       D8 DC
Decimal:  800        -9000
```

So 800-9000 = -8200 and it's in the range of -32768 to 32767. Perfect!, no integer overflow.

Here's an another example:

```
       Wav file 1  Wav file 2
       2nd Sample  2nd sample
Hex:     00 7D       20 03
Decimal: 32000        800
```

32000+800 = 32800. Oops!, an integer oveflow! :-(

My solution for this was to divide the samples by 2 by shifting the bits 1 bit to the right before adding them together.

For wav file 1.

```
Before shift.
Hex:     00 7D (little-endian)
Decimal: 32000
Binary:  0111 1101 0000 0000

After shift.
Hex:     80 3E (little-endian)
Decimal: 16000
Binary:  0011 1110 1000 0000
```

For wav file 2.

```
Before shift.
Hex:     20 03 (little-endian)
Decimal: 800
Binary:  0000 0011 0010 0000
After shift.
Hex:     90 10 (little-endian)
Decimal: 400
Binary:  0000 0001 1001 0000
```

Now we got:
16000+400=16400.

As for combining negative samples, we just convert it to positive, shift the bits to right by 1 bit, then convert it to negative.

But is this really the right way for combining samples?

Comment: Why the down vote? Was my explanation full of ambiguity? and/or not complete?. Can someone explain?

Comment: Your question doesn't fit in software engineering, therefore probably tge downvotes. It's just a beginner experience in signal processing. Working with signal samples can get arbitrarily complex. As a general guidance, the fewer rounding/truncation operations you have in your data path, the better (ideally exactly 1 at the end when you need to create integer values).

Comment: @Hans I know this might be late, but thanks for your suggestion! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no single correct way to add audio samples together.

The samples in a (uncompressed) WAV file represent the amplitude of the sound signal at the time the sample was taken. As the top-top amplitude of the signal is also a representation for how loud the sound is, halving all the sample values will also have an effect on the volume of the sound.

Besides halving the amplitude of the signals before combining them, you can also choose to clip the combined signal. In that case, if you add 32000 and 800, you clip the result to the largest value you can represent: 32768. Where reducing the amplitude has an effect on the volume, clipping can cause distortions in the audio when it is played back.

Which one to choose depends on how often you expect to get near or over the largest values you can represent in 16 bits and how your users will perceive the effects of either clipping or reducing the sample values.

If you intend to do more manipulations of the audio signal, it is best to internally use a larger datatype (e.g. 32 bits) and only do the halving or clipping at the very end when you need to have 16 bit sample values again for writing to the output. Then you could also dynamically decide on a strategy depending on how often and how far your sample values exceed the 16 bit range.